# Unable to Parse file correctly; Glob not working

Tags: regex, csv, perl, parsing, glob

I am trying to write a Perl script that basically checks if a particular file matching a regex exists in a particular directory. Here is my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

system ("grep PATH $ENV{MODEL_ROOT}/<....>/paths.tcl > \$MODEL_ROOT/hip_paths.csv");
system("sed -i 's/) /,/g' \$MODEL_ROOT/paths.csv");
system("sed -i 's/set G_L.*,//g' \$MODEL_ROOT/paths.csv");

my @glob;

my $file = "$ENV{MODEL_ROOT}/paths.csv" or die "CSV File is not present\n";
open(my $file_data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";

while (my @line = <$file_data>) {
  system ("printf \"@line\" >> fields"); #For debug
  foreach my $path (@line)
 {   
     $path =~ m/^.*proj\/(.*)\/<blah>/; #To find 'name'
     if (glob ("$path/*0p765v_125c*.ldb")) #Check if file exists in $path with said pattern
     {   
            @glob = glob ("$path/*0p765v_125c*.ldb");
            print "File exists for $1 in path $path: @glob\n"
     } 
     else 
     {
        print "Does not exist for $1 in path $path\n";
     } 
  }
}
close $file_data
```

**paths.csv** looks like this: (Cant post actual path due to TM and C issues)

```
/(path-to-proj)/proj/name1/version1/abc  
/(path-to-proj)/proj/name2/version2/abc  
/(path-to-proj)/proj/name3/version3/abc  
/(path-to-proj)/proj/name4/version4/abc  
/(path-to-proj)/proj/name5/version5/abc
```

(path to proj) is alphanumeric,
proj is alphabets only,
name<> is alpha-numeric and may contain underscores,
version<> is alpha-numeric

I know that all of these paths have a file that matches said pattern. However, the result of my code is something as shown below:

```
File exists for name1 in path /(path-to-proj)/proj/name1/version1/abc
: /(path-to-proj)/proj/name1/version1/abc
Does not exist for name2 in path /(path-to-proj)/proj/name2/version2/abc

File exists for name3 in path /(path-to-proj)/proj/name3/version3/abc
: /(path-to-proj)/proj/name3/version3/abc
Does not exist for name4 in path /(path-to-proj)/proj/name4/version4/abc
```

The results alternate between 'Exists' and 'Does not exist'.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's one complicated program! So is the objective: given a file with lines like `/path-to-proj/.../abc` check that files exist at those paths?  (But those files have more in their name, with that `0p765...`, right?).  Is that it?

Comment: One thing: You do realize that a thing like `@ary = <filehandle>` imposes list context on `<>` -- because there is an array on the lefthand side -- so that _all lines are read_ right at that point?  That still may work, since you then iterate over `@line` (bad name! it's _all lines_) but it's ... unusual, to say the least.

Comment: The `glob` in scalar context -- which you impose on it by using it as `if` condition -- iterates over filename expansions.  I don't see precisely how that'd fail you here but it's not what you want. Instead, retrieve filese, if any, in the condition: `if (my @files = glob(...)) { print ... }`

Comment: Tip: `while (my @lines = <$file_data>) { foreach my $path (@lines) { ... } }` is a weird way of writing `my @lines = <$file_data>; foreach my $path (@lines) { ... }`. Most people would use `while (my $path = <$file_data>) { ... }`

Comment: Tip: `my $file = "$ENV{MODEL_ROOT}/paths.csv" or die "CSV File is not present\n";` is a very weird way of writing `my $file = "$ENV{MODEL_ROOT}/paths.csv";`. Why did you ignore the warning???

Comment: Also: All that work by `grep` and two `sed`'s (that's a lot!) can nicely be done right in your script, in a short little loop over lines of that `$ENV.../paths.tcl` file, in basic Perl.

Comment: @ikegami I did not receive any warning for `my $file = "$ENV{MODEL_ROOT}/paths.csv" or die "CSV File is not present\n";`

Comment: @zdim Thanks for your comments, I am still learning everything! :) Have to catch up on a lot.

Comment: @zdim In a given directory, there are mutiple files (around 50). I only need to check if file(s) matching the said pattern exist for what I am about to do later on.

Comment: OK (that's not clear from the sample -- those `system` lines don't show "_multiple files_" ... unless `<...>` has shell globs?). Still, can do all that very nicely in Perl, is all I'm saying; but we can't hash it out here in comments...

Comment: Re "*did not receive any warning for*", Sorry, I miscopied the code when I tested it. The rest of the comment still applies, though.

Comment: @ikegami What is a better way to represent my code, should the said file (paths.csv) not exist?

Comment: No need to check. The `open` will fail with `$!` set to `ENOENT` (`No such file or directory`). In fact, checking in advance is a bad practice. The file could be deleted between the check and the `open`, so you end up relying on `open` anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operators (such as `glob`) function differently depending on whether they are evaluated in scalar context or list context.

`glob` in scalar context acts as an iterator. It returns the next match until it returns undef to indicate there is nothing left to return. It doesn't matter if the argument changes.

```
$ perl -e'for (1..7) { my $glob = glob("*"); CORE::say "$_ $glob"; }'
1 a.xml
2 b.xml
3 
4 a.xml
5 b.xml
6 
7 a.xml
```

You don't want that. You want to call it in list context. So replace

```
if (glob ("$path/*0p765v_125c*.ldb")) {
        @glob = glob ("$path/*0p765v_125c*.ldb");
```

with

```
if ( my @ldb_paths = glob("$path/*0p765v_125c*.ldb") ) {
```

or

```
if ( my ($ldb_path) = glob("$path/*0p765v_125c*.ldb") ) {
```

The second option gets just the first match, ignoring the rest. The parens on the left-hand side of the assignment are crucial to creating the necessary list context for the right-hand side.